# how to get the index of a document element with jquery in the following case?

Tags: jquery

I was wondering how to get the index of span with content itemEleven, with jquery in the following case. Assuming that we aren't able to get element by content value:

```
    <div>  
        <span class="itemSubMenu">itemOne</span>  
        <span class="itemSubMenu">itemTwo</span>  
        <span class="itemSubMenu">itemThree</span>  
        <span class="itemSubMenu">itemFour</span>  
        <span class="itemSubMenu">itemFive</span>  
        <span class="itemSubMenu">itemSix</span>  
        <span class="itemSubMenu">itemSeven</span>  
    </div>  
    <div>  
        <span class="subMenuitemSubMenu">Something</span>  
        <span class="subMenuitemSubMenu">Something too</span>  
    </div>  
    <div>  
        <span class="itemSubMenu">itemEight</span>  
        <span class="itemSubMenu">itemNine</span>  
        <span class="itemSubMenu">itemTen</span>  
        <span class="itemSubMenu">itemEleven</span>  
        <span class="itemSubMenu">itemTwelve</span>  
        <span class="itemSubMenu">itemThirteen</span>  
        <span class="itemSubMenu">itemFourteen</span>  
        <span class="itemSubMenu">itemFifteen</span>  
    </div>
```

When i try to get, for example, itemEight with the following method.

```
 $(".itemSubmenu").click(function(){
     alert($(this).index());  
 });
```

It alerts 0, instead 9. Assuming that it is zero-based-index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried

```
$(".itemSubMenu").index($(this));
```

inside of the click event?

Here is a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/3mDK5/

Comment: hm... I like this one even better... +1

Answer (score 2):

Index is always based on its index within its parent.

You'll need to do this:

```
$(".itemSubMenu").click(function() {
    alert($(this).parent().parent().find('span').index(this));  
});
```

But really you'd want some sort of contextual selector to base it off of:

```
$(".itemSubMenu").click(function() {
    alert($('#foo').find('span').index(this));  
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/THyAB/

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, had to fix a typo in his pasted code (itemSubmenu to itemSubMenu).  Should work now!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get the collection of spans with class `itemSubMenu` and then get the index of `this` from that collection to get the correct index.

```
var selected = $(this);
var myIndex = $("itemSubMenu").index(selected);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y73nE/)

I like this method.

```
$(".itemSubMenu").click(function(){
    var $this = this;
    var i;
    $(".itemSubMenu").each(function(idx,val){
       if(val === $this) console.log(i = idx);
    })
 });
```